# Unable to update organization properties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've encountered a problem while trying to update organization's properties using Microsoft Graph API. I've followed [these docs](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/organization_update) and tried it in [graph explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer).

My request looks like this:
`{ "displayName": "My Company Name" }`

Whatever I do I always get the following error:
`"error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "dfd9ae19-2774-4b10-8d74-f6f6cd21f712",
        "date": "2016-05-16T14:48:02"
    }
}`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried in my test tenant and results in the same error.

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/organization

In the above document it is mentioned that we can update "marketingNotificationMails" and "technicalNotificationMails" properties alone through **Update** API. So I think you can't update the organization display name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But do you know if there is a way to update the display name and other organization profile details anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear as though updates are limited on the organization entity.  Please file a request to [Uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis) to ask for this feature.